# Property does not exist on type react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm a newbie in typescript, could anyone please tell me why do I get this error?

> Property 'interval' does not exist on type 'App'.

```
interface State {
  userInput:string[];
  secondsPassed:number;
  }


class App extends React.Component<any, State>{
    state:State = {
      userInput:[],
      secondsPassed:0
    }
  startTimer = () => {
      this.interval = setInterval( () => {
        this.setState(() =>{
          return {secondsPassed: this.state.secondsPassed+1}
        })
      },1000)
    
  }
```

Comment: where is `interval` declared? `this` is pointing undefined that's why getting error.

Comment: Declaration of interval is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
 const interval = setInterval(() => {
    this.setState(() =>{
          return {secondsPassed: this.state.secondsPassed+1}
        })
      },1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Typescript is a statically-typed language. Part of that means you have to declare the variables of a class before its assignment. Simply declare `interval` as in the following:

```
class App extends React.Component<any, State>{
  interval

  state:State = {
    userInput:[],
    secondsPassed:0
  }
  startTimer = () => {
    this.interval = setInterval( () => {
      this.setState(() =>{
        return {secondsPassed: this.state.secondsPassed+1}
      })
    },1000)

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The first answer got it close, the solution looks like this:

```
 class App extends React.Component<any, State>{
      private interval: any ;
        state:State = {
          userInput:[],
          secondsPassed:0
        }
      startTimer = () => {
          this.interval = setInterval( () => {
            this.setState(() =>{
              return {secondsPassed: this.state.secondsPassed+1}
            })
          },1000)
        
      }
```